# lshw not showing individual memory bank info

Tags: ram

This is all I get:

```
sudo lshw -C memory
  *-memory                
       description: System memory
       physical id: 0
       size: 7981MiB
```

`sudo lshw` doesn't give any more info. `lshw` used to show individual memory banks.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

use :

```
 lshw -class memory
```

try it without sudo .

or use `sudo dmidecode --type 17`

Answer (score 2):

You can type this at terminal
**dmidecode**

Answer (score 1):

This is yet another regression bug of 16.04.

See this bug report:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lshw/+bug/1586473

As you can see in the link if you build lshw from source it works properly.

```
sudo apt-get source lshw
sudo checkinstall
```

http://wyldeplayground.net/ubuntu-ubuntu-16-04-aarch64-lshw-c-memory-did-not-show-memory-banks-info-correctly/

Answer (score 1):

Indeed this seems to be a bug with the `lshw` shipped with Ubuntu 15.10 and 16.04.

Similar to Kat Amsteram's answer, I fixed the issue by running:

```
sudo apt-get source lshw
sudo make
sudo make install
```